# Cannot scale or rotate objects

Tags: interface, objects

I choose the scale or rotate option that's on top of the render timeline, but every time I left click, the red circle with the 4 black lines sticking out (3D cursor) is selected, and not the scaling or rotating options. Is there any way I can fix this?

**EDIT: I have posted this on blender as a bug. Can someone who has enough reputation close this question as not constructive (ie this question is something that needs to be discussed not answered)? Thank you for all your help.**

**EDIT 2: This is my computer specific, please check my solution below.**

Comment: could you upload a screenshot?

Comment: [Video](http://youtu.be/cpDMaCC1AV0) uploaded.

Comment: You should not only click by `LMB`, but click and drag if using manipulator (either scale or rotate) (it's not clear good enough from video how exactly do you do that).

Comment: @MrZak what is the manipulator? And I did click and drag.

Comment: you have to click the LMB and drag at the same time (the LMB must be pushed while dragging)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26811/discussion-on-question-by-yu-bin-lee-cannot-scale-or-rotate-objects).

Comment: Should I report this as a bug in the blender.org site?

Comment: I think so. All ideas i can tell you are : update blender, update graphics card driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my computer's OpenGL issue, according to people at blender's bug support.
Downloading [this file](http://download.blender.org/ftp/sergey/softwaregl/win64/opengl32.dll) and putting it at the same folder where blender.exe is will fix the issue.

Comment: I'm glad that you could find the solution, and thanks for sharing it :)